# Is there a method to stop a slider from moving unless certain conditions are met?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, slider

Utilizing strictly SwiftUI, I am creating a fitness based application which provides the user their Calories, then breaks down said calories into macronutrients. What I am trying to accomplish is restricting the ability for the user to use the slider to increase the number of a macronutrient **unless** they reduce one of the other sliders.

For instance, if the user has 2000 Calories, we will say their macronutrient break down is as follows...

- 300 Carbohydrates
- 175 Protein
- 85 Fats

If the user reduces the number of carbohydrates, I want to allow them to increase a slider or sliders of their choice the same amount in which they reduce one of the sliders.

For instance, if the user reduces their Carbohydrates by 30, I want them to be able increase their Protein or Fats by that amount or a combination of both but by no ore the 30.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried? What have you found? What works and what doesn’t work from what you have tried and found?

Comment: Perhaps disable it at condition. The condition variable maybe as computed property, but don’t know if this would work.